# Oracle Data Miner(Need Tutorial)

Tags: oracle, data-mining

What does ODM(Oracle Data Miner) do?
Can you give me useful materials or a brief information about this option?

Thank you..

Comment: Please post anyone who has some experience with Oracle Data Miner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/datamining.html .

Answer (score 3):

It is for data analysts to help find patterns and relationships within data but there are APIs where you can use the analytics in your own applications.

There is a nice overview in wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Data_Mining

Just for fun (it is Friday) here is an amusing sales video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgVSu-4Mizs

And a **tutorial**: http://www.business-intelligence-quotient.com/?p=796